# Как заполнить treeview ( treenode ) данными из datatable?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть заполненная datatable экземплярами классов. В таблице есть столбы с названием Name и Name_of_Cement. Но в столбце Name есть повторяющиеся элементы. К примеру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как заполнить treeview ( treenode ) что бы выглядело примерно так, но с учетом того что таблица может дополняться одинаковыми Name

[image: *Порталанд *Вихрь *выфвфы]

Кажется все костыли перепробовал и ничего не помогло. Буду благодарен ответу

Прикрепляю структуру таблицы

```
 public DataTable todada<T>(IList<T> data)
    {

        PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

        props = props.Sort(new string[] { "Name", "NameOfCement", "Brand", "Manufacturer", "Clas", "price", "IDHL", "types" } );
        
        for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
            if (table.Columns.Contains(prop.Name))
            { }
            else
            {
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, typeof(string));
            }

        }

        
        object[] values = new object[props.Count];
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            table.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return table;
    }

        list_of_cemetns.add_roman("Романцемент", "Сибирь", 500, "РосЦемент", 40,5000 );
        list_of_cemetns.add_roman("Романцемент", "Вихрь", 600, "РосЦемент", 50, 4500);
        list_of_cemetns.add_port("Портланд", "Прой", 500, "РосЦемент", 50,4500,5000,"быстро");
        list_of_cemetns.add_aluma("Алумацемент", "Метель", 600, "РосЦемент", 50, 4500);
```

Comment: Структуру таблицы (таблиц?) в студию для начала. А вообще можете реализовать самый простой вариант - adj list: https://habr.com/en/post/46659/

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение в том чтобы сначала заполнить родительскую ветвь всеми элементами

```
foreach (DataRow v in table.Rows)
        {
            node.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(v[0].ToString());
        }
```

Затем пройтись по этим элементам и удалить повторяющиеся с помощью обычных циклов for ( до более рациональной штуки не додумался )

```
string x = " ";

for (int k = 0; k < node.Nodes[0.Nodes.Count; k++)
        {
            
            if (node.Nodes[0].Nodes[k].Text != x)
            {
                x = node.Nodes[0].Nodes[k].Text;
                
            }
            else
            {
                node.Nodes[0].Nodes.Remove(node.Nodes[0].Nodes[k]);
            }
        }
```

И затем заполнил его элементами из второго столбца с помощью switch

```
foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            if (col.ColumnName == "Name") 
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    switch (row[col.ColumnName].ToString())
                    {
                        case "Портланд":
                            node.Nodes[0].Nodes[r].Nodes.Add(row[1].ToString());
                            r++;
                            break;
                        case "Романцемент":
                            node.Nodes[0].Nodes[r].Nodes.Add(row[1].ToString());
                            break;
                        case "Алумацемент":
                            r++;
                            node.Nodes[0].Nodes[r].Nodes.Add(row[1].ToString());
                            break;
                    }
                }               
            }
        }
```